# recursive grep skipping/excluding/ignoring all subdirectories

Tags: grep, subdirectory

This is going to be my dumbest question yet. I'm sure it's stupidly obvious, but for the life of me, I could not find a solution.

I simply want to search all files in my current directory for a pattern, ignoring all subdirectories. Things I've tried:

`grep "mytext" .`-> complains that . is a directory

`grep -r "mytext" .` -> searches all subdirectories

`grep "mytext"` -> just freezes (searching entire machine?)

`grep -rd skip "mytext" .` -> skips current directory

Comment: grep "mytext" isn't freezing, it's waiting for input. Type something and hit enter and it'll try to match the expression against the text you entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My last attempt was on the right track. I figured I'd answer the question for posterity instead of just deleting it (which was tempting since I feel stupid for having to ask it in the first place).

The solution was to use the skip directories with a wildcard. i.e.

`grep -rd skip "mytext" ./*`

Comment: A slightly simpler version would be grep -r skip "mytext" *